# How to create two dimensional JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to create a two dimensional JSON object in java like this

```
{
    "0": {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Email": "abc@gmail.com"
    },
    "1": {
        "Name": "xyz",
        "Email": "xyz@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

Here is how I have created one-dimensional JSON

```
JSONObject contact = new JSONObject();
contact.put("Name", name);
contact.put("PhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
contact.put("Email", Email);
```

Now I have multiple contacts. SO I need a way to convert them into two dimensional JSON object.

How to do it?
P.S : I don't have much practical experience in java. Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need com.google.gson.* package

```
    JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject c0 = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject c1 = new JsonObject();

    root.add("0", c0);
    root.add("1", c1);

    c0.add("Name", new JsonPrimitive("ABC"));
    c0.add("Email", new JsonPrimitive("abc@gmail.com"));
    c1.add("Name", new JsonPrimitive("xyz"));
    c1.add("Email", new JsonPrimitive("xyz@gmail.com"));
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(root));
```

Get familiar with this type of hierarchical construction, you will use it a lot. Also, I wouldn't recommend using maps, when you have a whole API to help you manipulate JSON-s.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer gave me enough hint to solve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> m0 = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

m0.put("Name",  "ABC");
m0.put("Email", "abc@gmail.com");

m1.put("Name",  "xyz");
m1.put("Email", "xyz@gmail.com");

myMap.put("0", m1);
myMap.put("1", m2);
```

now you have this object in `myMap`, but i think you are not really understanding java

Comment: Maybe OP mean to convert it to appropriate JSON?

Comment: maybe, but he asked for json object... hard to really understand what he wants

Comment: I need to write a function which fetches all contacts from Android and returns the json object. Now each contacts have several details like name,email,phone,etc. So I am looking for ways to create two dimensional JSON object as specified in the question.

Comment: my answer will do it for you.